# Run Second Shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny UI for a user to choose an option from. I would like a secondary Shiny UI appear after closing the first application if the user chose Option 1.

How can I conditionally run a shiny application? Individually running these work but then when I test it together and putting it in an if statement seems to break it.

***EDIT::*** I would like to expand on this to not only just conditionally but if I want to run the same User Interface once with one option and have the user enter it and then run it again with different inputs I frequently have issues rendering the UI the second time. Would anyone know why this would be? I tried changing the ports and I even tried garbage collection and telling the system to sleep in between.

```
#First Application
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = "user_selection",
               label = "Please select one of the following options:",
               choices = c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"),
               selected = NULL),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit",
               label = "Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    selected_option <- input$user_selection
    assign("selected_option", selected_option, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    stopApp()
  })
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server,options=c(launch.browser = .rs.invokeShinyPaneViewer))




#If statment and second application
if (selected_option == "Option 1"){
   ui2 <- fluidPage(
    h3("Second UI")
    )
  server2 <- function(input, output) {
    }
 shinyApp(ui = ui2, server = server2,options=c(launch.browser = .rs.invokeShinyPaneViewer))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden tabPanels to achieve similar results.

Here is a reprex:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tab_container",
    type = "hidden",
    
    # First application:
    tabPanelBody(
      value = "first_ui",
      
      radioButtons(
        inputId = "user_selection",
        label = "Please select one of the following options:",
        choices = c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"),
        selected = NULL
      ),
      
      actionButton(
        inputId = "submit",
        label = "Submit"
      )
    ),
    
    # Second application:
    tabPanelBody(
      value = "second_ui",
      
      h3("Second UI")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$submit, {    
    if (input$user_selection == "Option 1") {
      updateTabsetPanel(
        session = session,
        inputId = "tab_container",
        selected = "second_ui"
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```